# How to Define Function Pointer Parameter Type for Method Overload in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm getting a compile error, and I'm not sure why.  (Please note, only in TS 2.4.1, 2.3.4 works just fine)  Below is an example with the compile error.  Yes you shouldn't create an overload in this case but just a union type for the function signature, but this is the simplest example I could create to show the issue:

```
class Animal {
    a: string;
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    b: string;
}

function test(func: (p: Dog) => any): any;
function test(func: (p: Animal) => any): any;
function test(func: (p: Animal) => any): any {

    return undefined;
}
```

I'm getting a TS2394 Compiler error:

> Overload signature is not compatible with function implementation

for this line:

```
function test(func: (p: Dog) => any): any;
```

Changing function definition the below resolves the compile error:

```
function test(func: (p: any) => any): any {
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: @Aron Overload signature is not compatible with function implementation

Comment: What if you do `function test(func: (p: Dog | Animal) => any): any {`?

Comment: @Aron, Nope.  has to be any

Comment: Actually `function test(func: (p:Dog) => any): any {` works

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @jcalz Joe Calzaretta, I've figured this out (https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17162).

2.4 introduced [Strict contravariance for callback parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-4.html#strict-contravariance-for-callback-parameters)  Copied from Joe:

> Let's call (p: Dog) => any a Dog-consumer, and (p: Animal) => any an
>   Animal-consumer. Note that every Animal-consumer is a Dog-consumer
>   (because something that consumes animals will accept a dog), but not
>   every Dog-consumer is an Animal-consumer (because something that
>   consumes dogs might not accept, say, a cat). That means that
>   Dog-consumer is a supertype of Animal-consumer. Since one overload
>   takes a Dog-consumer, and the other takes an Animal-consumer, the
>   implementation should take a supertype of these: Dog-consumer.

```
function test(func: (p: Dog) => any): any;
function test(func: (p: Animal) => any): any;
function test(func: (p: Dog | Animal) => any): any {
```

Does not work since you can't give the Dog Consumer an Animal, it needs a dog.  The most typed method of representing this is as follows:

```
function test(func: (p: Dog) => any): any;
function test(func: (p: Animal) => any): any;
function test(func: ((p: Animal) => any) | ((p:Dog) => any)): any {
```

Where `func` can be either a function that takes an animal, or a function that takes a dog.