# How to Cleanly Write a TypeScript Function With Different Callback Overload Parameters

Tags: typescript, typescript2.4

This is an extension of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45085301/how-to-define-function-pointer-parameter-type-for-method-overload-in-typescript?noredirect=1#comment77143588_45085301)

Given this code:

```ts
class Animal {
    a: string;
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    b: string;
}

class Foo<T>{}

function test<T,A extends Dog>(animal:A, func: (p: A) => T): T;
function test<T,A extends Animal>(animal:A, func: (p: A) => Foo<T>): Foo<T>;
function test<T,A extends Animal>(animal:A, func: (p: A) => T|Foo<T>): T|Foo<T> {
    return func(animal);
}
```

is there a cleaner way of writing the overload that doesn't require the A type Parameter? Or maybe a cleaner of writing any of it?  Basically the function conditionally calls the given `func` with the given `animal`.  If given a dog, type `T` is returned.  If given some other animal, a type `Foo<T>` is returned.

### Update 1

I was unable to get @jcalz version to work, but it took me a while to realize it was related to promises, but I'm not sure how to resolve the issue.  Below is my "ugly but it works" methodology, and @jalz's "it's nice but it's broke" methodology:

```ts
class Animal {
    a: string;
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    b: string;
}

class Foo<T>{ }

function test<T, A extends Dog>(animal: A, func: (p: A) => Promise<T>): Promise<T>;
function test<T, A extends Animal>(animal: A, func: (p: A) => Promise<Foo<T>>): Promise<Foo<T>>;
function test<T, A extends Animal>(animal: A, func: (p: A) => Promise<T> | Promise<Foo<T>>): Promise<T | Foo<T>> {
    return func(animal);
}

const foo: Promise<Foo<string>> = test(new Animal(), (a) => { return Promise.resolve(new Foo<string>()); });
const other: Promise<string> = test(new Dog(), (d) => { return Promise.resolve(d.b); });

type AnimalFunc<T> = {
    (dog: Dog): Promise<T>;
    (animal: Animal): Promise<Foo<T>>;
}

function test2<T>(dog: Dog, func: AnimalFunc<T>): Promise<T>;
function test2<T>(animal: Animal, func: AnimalFunc<T>): Promise<Foo<T>>;
function test2<T>(animal: Animal, func: AnimalFunc<T>): Promise<T | Foo<T>> {
    return func(animal);
}

const foo2: Promise<Foo<string>>  = test2(new Animal(),
    (a) => {
        return Promise.resolve(new Foo<string>());
    }); // Errors: TS2345   Argument of type '(a: any) => Promise<Foo<string>>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnimalFunc<string>'.
        // Type 'Promise<Foo<string>>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<string>'.
        // Type 'Foo<string>' is not assignable to type 'string'.TypeScript Virtual Projects    C: \_Dev\CRM\WebResources\webresources\new_\scripts\Payment.ts  498 Active

const other2: Promise<string>  = test2(new Dog(), (d) => { return Promise.resolve(d.b); });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand

> the function conditionally calls the given `func` with the given `animal`. If given a dog, type `T` is returned. If given some other animal, a type `Foo<T>` is returned.

to mean that the parameter `func` accepts all `Animal` inputs but will return different types depending on whether its input is a `Dog` or not.  That means I would declare `func` to of the following overloaded type:

```
type AnimalFunc<T> = {
    (dog: Dog): T;
    (animal: Animal): Foo<T>;
}
```

Then, the function `test` just passes its `animal` input to its `func` input and returns whatever type it gets back.  To get that to happen, I would declare `test` like this:

```
function test<T>(dog: Dog, func: AnimalFunc<T>): T;
function test<T>(animal: Animal, func: AnimalFunc<T>): Foo<T>;
function test<T>(animal: Animal, func: AnimalFunc<T>): T | Foo<T> {
    return func(animal);
}
```

Hope that helps.

---

#### Update 1

@daryl [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45087264/how-to-cleanly-write-a-typescript-function-with-different-callback-overload-para#comment77187606_45092007):

> This works for the definition, but not call sites. If I pass in a dog as the first parameter, my function must accept a dog and return an T, else it must accept an animal and return a Foo, At the call sites, it complains the the function isn't returning the other type (T or Foo)

Without knowing all your use cases I can't tell what the best definition would be.  If you really have a function of type `AnimalFunc<T>` it should work:

```
function func1(dog: Dog): string;    
function func1(animal: Animal): Foo<string>;
function func1(animal: Animal): string | Foo<string> {
  if (animal instanceof Dog) {
    return "woof";
  }
  return new Foo<string>();
};

var dog: Dog = new Dog();
var cat: Animal = new Animal();
var dogTest: string = test(dog, func1);
var catTest: Foo<string> = test(cat, func1);
```

If you are trying to pass in a different type of function, please spell out the use cases.  Thanks.

---

#### Update 2

@daryl [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45087264/how-to-cleanly-write-a-typescript-function-with-different-callback-overload-para#comment77192644_45092007):

> This works for the definition, but not call sites. If I pass in a dog as the first parameter, my function must accept a dog and return an T, else it must accept an animal and return a Foo, At the call sites, it complains the the function isn't returning the other type (T or Foo)

Okay, I don't think this has much to do with `Promise`s.  It looks like you want `func` to *either* take a `Dog` and return a `Promise<T>`, *or* take an `Animal` and return a `Promise<Foo<T>>`, but not necessarily both.  That is, a particular `func` might only want a `Dog` and will not accept a `Cat`.  That's not how I understood it originally.

For this case, then I'd say you want to do:

```
function test3<T>(dog: Dog, func: (dog: Dog) => Promise<T>): Promise<T>;
function test3<T>(animal: Animal, func: (animal: Animal) => Promise<Foo<T>>): Promise<Foo<T>>;
function test3<T, A extends Animal>(animal: A, func: (animal: A) => Promise<T> | Promise<Foo<T>>): Promise<T> | Promise<Foo<T>> {
  return func(animal);
}
```

Note that the declarations of `test3` (the top two lines) are typed for the benefit of the *caller*, while the implementation (the third line) is typed for the benefit of the *implementer*.  If all you care about is type safety for people calling `test3` but are secure enough in your implementation that you don't need TS to verify the types for you, then you can just implement it as:

```
function test3<T>(dog: Dog, func: (dog: Dog) => Promise<T>): Promise<T>;
function test3<T>(animal: Animal, func: (animal: Animal) => Promise<Foo<T>>): Promise<Foo<T>>;
function test3(animal: any, func: any): any {
  return func(animal); // fine, but even return animal(func) would be accepted here, to disastrous results at runtime
}
```

The implementation signature with the generic `A` is about as specific as I think I can get.  It accepts any type of animal `A` for `animal`, and a function `func` that will definitely accept `animal` and return either a `Promise<T>` or a `Promise<Foo<T>>`.  This is safe enough for calling `func(animal)`, but you could still fool the typechecker by having an implementation like

```
function test3<T, A extends Animal>(animal: A, func: (animal: A) => Promise<T> | Promise<Foo<T>>): Promise<T> | Promise<Foo<T>> {
  return Promise.resolve(new Foo<T>()); // no error!!
}
```

which would cause problems with the first overload declaration since it doesn't ever return a `Promise<T>`.

I hope this has helped.

Comment: This works for the definition, but not call sites.  If I pass in a dog as the first parameter, my function must accept a dog and return an T, else it must accept an animal and return a Foo<T>,  At the call sites, it complains the the function isn't returning the other type (T or Foo<T>)

Comment: Ah, I am actually returning promises and that is messing things up for me, but I don't know how to fix it.  I've updated my answer with a working broken example.

Comment: Awesome.  You basically have what i have, but I didn't realize you don't have to have generic types defined for the overloads.  That does make it simpler.  The one other suggestion I would make is to use `Promise<T | Foo<T>>` vs `Promise<T> | Promise<Foo<T>>`